# Forcing Client to Close Object

Tags: java, class, oop, object

I have made a custom class which comes complete with a `.close()`method. I was wondering how do I force the client to always call this method after using my object to ensure that the object appropriately closes and frees up any resources it was using?

I.E:
Suppose I have an object

```
public MyObject {
     public MyObject() {

     }
     method1() {
     //do some stuff.
     }
     method2() {
     //do some other stuff.
     }
     close(){
     //cleans up resources utilized by this object.
     }
}
```

and a client:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyObject my = new MyObject();
     my.method1();
     my.method2();
     my.close();
}
```

The above should work. However,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     MyObject my = new MyObject();
     my.method1();
     my.method2();
}
```

should not work (ideally not compile or give a warning of some kind) because the object is never closed after using it.

Comment: I don't thinks that's possible (AFAIK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have made a custom class which comes complete with a .close()method. I was wondering how do I force the client to always call this method after using my object to ensure that the object appropriately closes and frees up any resources it was using?

I'd suggest to let your class implement the AutoClosable interface and use `try with resource`:

```
public MyObject implements AutoCloseable{
     // ...
     @Override
     close(){
     //cleans up resources utilized by this object.
     }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
   try(MyObject my = new MyObject();){
        my.method1();
        my.method2();
   } // calls 'close()' when leaving this block even when exception occures
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing Closeable. Still works the way I was hoping though. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing Closable or Autoclosable interfaces.

http://java.meritcampus.com/core-java-topics/autocloseable-closeable-and-flushable-interfaces-in-java

Answer (score 0):

I want to comment but since I do not have enough reputation I write it as an answer.

As mentioned in the answers, you can implement AutoCloseable, but if you do not want to implement it, another idea is to add init() method where you will initiate ressources and in each method body call init() at the begining and close() at the end.

Your code will be like:

```
public MyObject {
    public MyObject() {

    }
    init() {
        //initiate ressources.
    }
    method1() {
        init();
        //do some other stuff.
        close();
    }
    close(){
        //cleans up resources utilized by this object.
    }
}
```

But if performance is key factor it should be better to implement AutoCloseable.